# Packing 4 Integers as ONE BYTE?

Tags: python, binary, struct

I have four integers {`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`} that can have the following range of values:

`a` - {0 or 1}    (1 bit)

`b` - {0 or 1}    (1 bit)

`c` - {0, 1, 2, ..., 7}    (3 bits)

`d` - {0, 1, 2, ..., 7}    (3 bits)

at first, I would like to pack them into a one byte that can be then written to a binary file.
later, I would like to unpack that one byte and get from it to a tuple of the form (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`).

I know how to read/write a byte to a binary file in python. But how do I do the bits packing/unpacking?

Comment: If you need to do this a lot, check out http://construct.wikispaces.com/ and https://bitbucket.org/haypo/hachoir/wiki/Home which both pack and unpack according to a declarative format definition.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use shift and bitwise OR, then convert to a character to get a "byte":

```
x = chr(a | (b << 1) | (c << 2) | (d << 5))
```

To unpack this byte again, first convert to an integer, then shift and use bitwise AND:

```
i = ord(x)
a = i & 1
b = (i >> 1) & 1
c = (i >> 2) & 7
d = (i >> 5) & 7
```

Explanation:  Initially, you have

```
0000000a
0000000b
00000ccc
00000ddd
```

The left-shifts give you

```
0000000a
000000b0
000ccc00
ddd00000
```

The bitwise OR results in

```
dddcccba
```

Converting to a character will convert this to a single byte.

Unpacking:  The four different right-shifts result in

```
dddcccba
0dddcccb
00dddccc
00000ddd
```

Masking (bitwise AND) with `1` (`0b00000001`) or `7` (`0b00000111`) results in

```
0000000a
0000000b
00000ccc
00000ddd
```

again.

Comment: Note that strings are only strings of bytes in Python 2; in Python 3 they're Unicode, so `chr(x)` will actually give you a 2- or 4-byte word.  You'll want to construct an actual `bytes` object instead of a string.  I'm not sure off-hand what the `bytes` equivalent of `chr` is, if there is one.

Comment: (I think the correct thing to do is generally as sjr does: simply return it as an int, and handle changing it to a single byte at the point you actually use it.)

Comment: I also favour ANDing before you do the bit shift in constructing the byte to ensure that the the data is of the expected width.  Other wise you can get all sorts of nasty and subtle errors.

Comment: @Glenn: regarding your first comment:  Very good point.  It would probably be best to use `bytearray.append()` for the conversion from integer to byte and and item access on a `bytearray` for the conversion back.  This would work in Python 2.6 or newer.

Comment: @Peter: You may as well just assert your requirements, eg. `assert 0 <= a <= 1, a`; if that's what you expect to receive, then it's better to throw an error if you get invalid data instead of silently returning something bogus.

Comment: @Glen Maynard .. point taken.  I suppose its a question of philosophy.  In general the stuff I work on has a greater penalty for stopping than producing erroneous data under a specific set of circumstances - so that has coloured my thinking towards not throwing an error.  Although "correct data in" is still the better option!

Comment: @GlennMaynard:  Using assert for data validation is a bad idea -- if/when somebody runs your program with optimization turned on, the asserts (and your checks) are removed.

Comment: @Ethan: Checking for invalid parameters (programming errors) is exactly the sort of thing you *want* removed by that optimization.  If you want a check that's *intended* to be thrown and caught in production, then you don't want AssertionError anyway; you probably want ValueError.

Answer (score 10):

```
def encode(a, b, c, d):
  return a | b << 1 | c << 2 | d << 5

def decode(x):
  return x & 1, (x >> 1) & 1, (x >> 2) & 7, (x >> 5) & 7
```

Comment: Note that the parentheses around multiple return values are typically omitted in Python: `return x & 1, (x >> 1) & 1, (x >> 2) & 7, (x >> 5) & 7)`.

Comment: Note that you have a hanging closing paranthesis. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you need to this kind of thing a lot then bit shifting can become tedious and error prone. There are third-party libraries that can help - I wrote one called [bitstring](http://python-bitstring.googlecode.com):

To pack and convert to a byte:

```
x = bitstring.pack('2*uint:1, 2*uint:3', a, b, c, d).bytes
```

and to unpack:

```
a, b, c, d = bitstring.BitArray(bytes=x).unpack('2*uint:1, 2*uint:3')
```

This is probably overkill for your example, but it's helpful when things get more complicated.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty simple. Mask (for range), shift them into place, and or them together.

```
packed = ((a & 1) << 7) | ((b & 1) << 6) | ((c & 7) << 3) | (d & 7)

a = (packed >> 7) & 1
b = (packed >> 6) & 1
c = (packed >> 3) & 7
d = packed & 7
```

Answer (score 0):

> nested arithmetic form (NAF) :

```
p = 8 * (8 * (2 * a + b) + c) + d                  # "a" at MSB
p =               a + (b + (c + d * 8) * 2) * 2    # "a" at LSB
```

> nested shifting form (NSF) :

```
p = ( ( ( ( (a << 1) + b) << 3) + c) << 3) + d     # "a" at MSB
p = ( ( ( ( (d << 3) + c) << 1) + b) << 1) + a     # "a" at LSB
```

Personally I think NAF is much cleaner (even if not the fastest), because it keeps all the digit groups on the same side and all the scaling factors on the other regardless of endian-ness, all while minimizing the layers of nesting required, and total arithmetic ops.

*"NAF" and "NSF" aren't formal terms - it's just a colloquial way of describing them*

---

So packing it would be `chr(p)` or just `sprintf("%c", p)`

as for decoding, using the **"a" at MSB** approach, it's basically splitting out a byte's octal codes back out to its components (**"a" at LSB** is the same decoding process in little-endian)  :

```
     2a+b c  d   a  b
        \  \/     \/
======================
62      \0 76     00
63      \0 77     00
64      \1 00     01
65      \1 01     01

126     \1 76     01
127     \1 77     01
128     \2 00     10
129     \2 01     10

190     \2 76     10
191     \2 77     10
192     \3 00     11
193     \3 01     11

254     \3 76     11
255     \3 77     11
0       \0 00     00
1       \0 01     00
```

`2a+b` is really useful when it comes to encoding `UTF-8` :

> `\0 ##` - all the `ASCII` digits and arithmetic operators,
> most of the `ASCII` linguistic punctuation symbols, and
> nearly all the `ASCII` `[[:cntrl:]]` bytes (sans `\177 DEL`)

> `\1 ##` - all the `ASCII` letters, plus misc `[[:punct:]]`

---

> `\2 ##` - **trailing**/"continuation" bytes for `Unicode` code points `U+0080 - U+10FFFFF`

> `\3 ##` - all the **leading** byte for `Unicode` code points `U+0080 - U+10FFFFF`

— sans `\300 xC0` - `\301 xC1` and `\365 xF5` - `\377 xFF`