# Packing 4 Integers as ONE INTEGER?

Tags: python, binary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Packing 4 Integers as ONE BYTE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302374/packing-4-integers-as-one-byte)

I have four integers {`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`} that can have the following range of values:

`a` - {0 or 1}    (1 bit)

`b` - {0 or 1}    (1 bit)

`c` - {0, 1, 2, ..., 7}    (3 bits)

`d` - {0, 1, 2, ..., 7}    (3 bits)

Is it possible to 'convert' them to ONE INTEGER (between 0 - 255) without having to do bit packing/unpacking? if so, how do I achieve this in Python?

Comment: Those are very strange integer sizes you will almost certainly have to do bit manipulations to group those together.

Comment: @user540009 In essence, you seem to be asking how to do bit manipulation without doing bit manipulation.

Comment: well 3 + 3 + 1 + 1 = 8bits so a byte can hold that but... you will have to do bit masking to retrieve and save the values, not sure why you would go to the trouble especially in python since you don't want that overhead

Comment: I need to save them to a file. and this will help me store data for 4 parameters in just one byte, thus saving disk space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Equivalently to [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302374/packing-4-integers-as-one-byte/5302410#5302410), but using `*` and `+` instead of `<<` and `|`, you can do

```
i = a + 2*b + 4*c + 32*d
```

for packing and

```
a, b, c, d = i % 2, i//2 % 2, i//4 % 8, i//32 % 8
```

for unpacking.  This does the same [as the bit operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302374/packing-4-integers-as-one-byte/5302410#5302410), just without using bit operations.  I don't see the point, but you asked for it.

Comment: Under the hood, though, aren't the multiplications implemented as left shifts anyway?  (+1 BTW)

Comment: @Sven Marnach: thank you for this answer!  now I don't have to deal with bit manipulations, I will just convert the four items to one byte, pack it using `struct` and write to file! and to unpack, I will read a byte from the file using `struct`, unpack it, and get the actual numbers. you've saved me from doing bit manipulations!

Comment: @useruser540009: What's wrong with bit manipulations?  And these are just bit manipulations in disguise anyway.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: nothing is wrong. Yet, this solution is more understandable to a human eye than bits (at least, to me). I was not sure there was a way to do this without bits, hence I asked about doing this using bits. But now that I see it's possible, I will be using this version of the code instead of the bits.

Comment: @user540009: The *vast* majority of programmers that are used to this kind of problem would find bitwise operations *clearer* than multiplications and divisions.  Certainly, the *intent* of packing values into a single byte is much clearer when using bitwise operations.

Comment: @Daniel Pryden: you might be right. I guess I am more used to 'regular' operations such a `*` and `/`

Answer (score 6):

If you mean that *you* don't want to do the bit packing and unpacking, [ctypes.Structure](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#bit-fields-in-structures-and-unions) provides these facilites.

For example:

```
from ctypes import *
class Int(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a", c_int, 1), ("b", c_int, 1),
                ("c", c_int, 3), ("d", c_int, 3)]

p = Int()
p.a = 1
p.b = 0
p.c = 7
p.d = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of this is useless, since he asked for it to be packed into a 1 byte integer...

---

Since these are all smaller than a char, you could do the following:

```
import struct
print struct.pack('cccc', a, b, c, d)
```

That will give you a 4 byte integer.

Comment: perfect, exactly what I intend to do.

Comment: @user540009: But this will pack into four bytes (32 bits) instead of one byte (8 bits).  Which is it that you want?

Comment: @Daniel Pryden: thank you for bringing this to my attention. I will pack it in one byte ('c').