# what is a fast and simple way of packing signed values in 4 bits?

Tags: python

I have a python list of integers, each being in the range [-8,7]. I want to pack these values into an array of bytes that i will send down a socket connection. Since these values can be represented by 4 bits in a two's complement representation, it should be possible to pack two such values in each byte. What is a good and relatively fast way of doing this in python? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried googling for answers to this?  I can't believe someone hasn't answered this already. At least show one solution and comment on why it doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two's Complement in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604464/twos-complement-in-python)

Comment: @Bill this looks more relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302374

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def pack_integer(integers):
    packed_byte = bytearray() 
    current_byte = 0
    bit_position = 0
    for integer in integers:
        integer = max(-16,min(integer, 15))
        if integer < 0:
            integer += 32
        current_byte |= (integer & Ox1F) << bit_position
        bit_position += 4
        if bit_position >= 8:
           packed_bytes.append(current_byte)
           current_byte = 0
           bit_position = 0
       if bit_position > 0:
           packed_bytes.append(current_byte)
       return packed_bytes
```